# Material TextInputEditText not able to center hint and to keep input value moved to bottom

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

On https://material.io/components/text-fields there is an interactive demo for Filled TextField.
Label hint is centered inside input field and when you click on it and enter some text, label moves up and text that you inputed is slightly below center(below where hint previously was)

Problem is that I am not able to reproduce this behaviour on Android as text that I input stays in the same position as a placeholder.

Not centered hint and icon, but they should be
[image]

This is correct, as the label is moved up and password is below center line
[image]

Code:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/et_password"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tiet_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/formTextAppearance">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/firstNameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:background="@null"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLength="150"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

@styles ...

```
<style name="formTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Hm, this does not solve my problem. Why do you think it should? What is the main difference?